# Override a shared library function in swift

Tags: swift

I have a shared library that exposes a function/type and i'm trying to use in swift. The following is from the header file.

```
typedef void (*ConnectingCallback)(const enum ConnectionState *state, const void *user_data);
```

The library checks for connecting devices on the network and fires this callback when one is found. In the java implementation  (not totally the same beast) the above is an abstract and is overridden. This does not seem to be the case in swift.

Any advice on starting points would be gratefully received.

Comment: That line is the definition of a block/closure in Objective-C, so by just looking at that we can't tell you for certain how to use it. You'll probably find a property with the type `ConnectingCallback` somewhere in the code that you can set to a closure that handles that callback.

Comment: Wellcome to SO! :) This is a type definition, you can't "override" it. There is likely a function in that library which takes a parameter of this function pointer. Likely, you are supposed to define a function in your app and set it as a parameter. So, what are you trying to accomplish?